# How can one read an integer bit by bit in Java?

Tags: java

I would like to take an int as input, and return the kth bit.

```
int getBit(int n, int k){
    return kth bit in n;
}
```

How would i do this?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Using bitwise operators:

```
int getBit(int n, int k) {
    return (n >> k) & 1;
}
```

Explanation (in bits):

```
n
100010101011101010 (example)
n >> 5
000001000101010111 (all bits are moved over 5 spots, therefore
&                   the bit you want is at the end)
000000000000000001 (0 means it will always be 0,
=                   1 means that it will keep the old value)
1
```

Comment: this is starting from the least significant bit as the 0th bit right?

Comment: @user1921187 Yes, it is. `getBit(0b10001, 0)` would return `1`, and `getBit(0b10001, 1)` would return `0`.

Comment: well, if I ran getBit(n, 0), I would get the 2nd bit from the right. So k=0 would actually get me the least significant bit, so it is the 0th bit. Am i seeing something wrong?

Comment: @user1921187 Sorry, I edited my comment. I wasn't thinking :P If you ran `getBit(n, 0)`, you would get the last bit.

Comment: Valid answer. Just another thought on this is, left shifting 1 by k times and checking.

n & (1 << k)

Answer (score 13):

```
return (n >> k) & 1;
```

Here, `n >> k` shifts the `k`-th bit into the least significant position, and `& 1` masks out everything else.

Answer (score 6):

If lowest significant bit is bit number `0`:

```
return (n>>k)&1;
```

Answer (score 4):

or use:

```
boolean getBit(int n, int k) {
    return ((n >> k) & 1) == 1;
}
```

if you want a boolean value

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the module property for this. If your number is even the lowest significant bit is zero, otherwise (odd) is one.

```
return (n>>k)%2;
```